# Pass simple arithmetic expression as parameter of method in C#

Tags: c#

I have school assignment that I need to solve but I'm not sure how to do it.
I need to create method Calculate (in class Example)

Example.Calculate(5+10);

This method receives arithmetic expression(NOT string) of two numbers and calculates it's value. Is it possible to pass parameter as expression in C# and how to do it?

Comment: Look into ExpressionTree

Comment: It is not clear what you want here. "Pass parameter as expression"? Can you clarify what you want done?

Comment: It is not possible to pass an arithmetic expression to a method in exactly the way you show in your example, and still have _the method_ perform the calculation (which seems to be a requirement). So either the answer to your question is "you can't", or you need to edit your question so that the example shows something you _can_ do.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this school assignment is also unclear and in the first moment I thought that it has some mistake. Anyway, the answer that Amir Popovich gave down below will help me, but I'll also try Expression tree too. Thanks guys for helping

Answer (score 5):

Yes you could use an [Expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) like so:

```
public class Example
{
    public static int Calculate(Expression<Func<int>> expr)
    {
       return expr.Compile()();
    }
}
void Main()
{
    var mult = Example.Calculate(() => 4 * 3); //returns 12
    var add = Example.Calculate(() => 4 + 3);  // returns 7
}
```

But in this case you could might as well skip the expression tree and just use a lambda:

```
public static int Calculate(Func<int> expr)
{
   return expr();
}
```

Comment: Unless he needs to inspect the expression tree somehow, a delegate is probably easier.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try this solution and the solution that Amir Popovich gave too. Unfortunatelly task is uclear to me also.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply with a small trick:

```
public class Example
{
   public static T Calculate<T>(T calculation)
   {
      return calculation;
   }
}

var val1 = Example.Calculate(5+10);
var val2 = Example.Calculate(5*10);
```

Comment: Other than having a method that will use `T` as `double` when passing in `double` values, what would this accomplish? The calculation would still be done by the compiler at compile-time, passing in a constant value to the method.

Comment: I simply answered his question. Since this is a school task I dont think they want him to create expressions or delegates(Why is invoking a delegate in runtime better?). I agree that this code is pure bullshit and I wouldn't use it in real-life.

Comment: Thanks Amir, I'll definitively try your solution first, since it is a school assignment, and this solution is simple